# objective c for loop on NSArray count

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsarray

Does anyone know why...

Items is an allocated and initialised NSArray* with zero items inside it

```
for (int i = 0;i < [Items count];i++){

   // WORK FINE DOES NOT ENTER

}

for (int i = 0;i <= [Items count]-1;i++){

   // ENTERS INCORRECTLY!!!

}
```

Comment: also if I use a temporary variable like int upperbound = [Items count]-1 in the second scenario it works as well.

Comment: `count` returns an unsigned number...

Comment: Cheers everyone I will accept the answer when it lets me ... in 8 mins

Comment: BTW:  `Items` should be `items`;  variables in Objective-C should always start with a lowercase letter (as should methods).  Class names are capitalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count is declared as `- (NSUInteger)count`, so it returns an unsigned integer (or long on 64 bit), and `0 - 1` becomes `NSUIntegerMax` which on 32 bit is 4billion and a bit (and on 64 bit a much much larger number).

Comment: Thank you I thought I was going mad